# Using Sparql query to identify category/classification of an entity

Tags: java, sparql, dbpedia

I am new to DBpedia and Sparql. What I am trying to do is extract entities from text (which I am able to do) and query DBpedia to check if their category is that of a person, location or organization. I am not sure if there is a straightforward query for this as a person may also belong to several other categories like actor or singer or scientist. But maybe if I got a few results I could look at some generic keywords that are associated with a person, location and organization. I found a query that may work for me:

```
PREFIX dbres: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
select ?o where {dbres:basketball rdf:type ?o} LIMIT 10
```

But how do I make this generic i.e how do I not make it specific to basketball and instead have a variable in place of basketball whose value will keep changing based on the entity value. Also, I need to use this in java code so how do I change this so that my java code can understand?

Comment: I don't understand the problem? Why can't you build the SPARQL query dynamically for each extracted entity? Isn't it simply changing the subject URI? Or do I miss something?

Comment: @AKSW Honestly, I won't know how to do that as I have never written SPARQL queries before. Like I said I am new to this hence reaching out to you guys to help with this. I figured what I have posted would work. but if there is a better way I am definitely open to it.

Comment: The way is that you use is ok. But there is no guarantee that a) the entity exists in DBpedia b) the used URI is the one that exists in DBpedia for the entity that you mean (think about synonyms). For example, in your query you're asking for types of http://dbpedia.org/resource/basketball . If you open that URI in the browser you'll see no data. If you use the URI http://dbpedia.org/resource/Basketball instead, you'll see data. It's case sensitive. For other entities you can also try to find data by using `http://dbpedia.org/resource/` + the entity token - yet it might not lead to any results.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use REGEX on the labels of resources in DBpedia: `select distinct ?o where {?s rdf:type ?o . ?s rdfs:label ?l . FILTER(REGEX(str(?l), 'basketball' ,'i'))} LIMIT 10`, but this might be slow.

Comment: Or apply the REGEX on the URIs directly: `select distinct ?o where {?s rdf:type ?o .  FILTER(REGEX(str(?s), 'basketball' ,'i'))} LIMIT 10`

Comment: Note, both queries will probably return useless things since it just matches strings, i.e. any resource whose name (resp. URI) contains the token`basketball` like e.g. http://dbpedia.org/resource/Blake_Williams_(basketball) or http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Basketball_leagues_in_Canada

Comment: @AKSW Got it. Thanks! How about this? I got this from another question you answered and this may work better however it always gives me a false - PREFIX dbres: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
ASK { ?s rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Jackson> 
values ?person { foaf:Person dbo:Person } ?s a ?person }

Comment: I guess you want to ask whether Jackson is a person. But the encoding in RDF is `<RESOURCE_URI> a <CLASS_URI>`. And the URI is also wrong, it starts with a protocol (usually `http:`) or you use the prefix: `PREFIX dbres: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> 
ASK { values ?person { foaf:Person dbo:Person } dbres:Jackson a ?person }` . But as I told you, I don't know what you expect as result. There is probably no data for Jackson in DBpdia

Comment: @serendipity, have you tried [DBpedia Spotlight](http://www.dbpedia-spotlight.org/spotlight-api)?

Comment: @StanislavKralin Thanks so much for the recommendation! I'm going to use spotlight instead as it seems much simpler and exactly what I need to help classify my entities. I did some research and most code samples I found are working on paragraphs using their paragraph annotator. I couldn't find an annotator that works on smaller text like words. Would you know about this Maybe I should ask this as a separate question.

Comment: @serendipity, the only thing I know about DBpedia Spotlight, is that "The models are probabilistic and rely on the context of the text used. The greater the content - in words - the more efficient the disambiguation process, thus increasing the assertiveness of the provided links." (from [FAQ](https://github.com/dbpedia-spotlight/dbpedia-spotlight/wiki/FAQ)) :-(.

Comment: @StanislavKralin No worries. This is very insightful! Thanks again!

Comment: @serendipity, I think, decreasing the `confidence` value will help sometime.